# Byobu tmux pane borders

Tags: byobu

When I am using my normal thing it looks like this:

http://timramich.com/random/ssh-big.png

If I log in from another client that uses fewer rows and columns, it looks like this:

http://timramich.com/random/ssh-small.png

Why does the large one not have the active border on the right? The right-most border is not there on the smaller device, as well.

Answer (score 2):

If you log in from different screen sizes, byobu adjusts to the smaller one. If you want your big screen size back, Atl-F6 will close all connection but yourself.